# How to concatenate two arrays together with a space in between the two strings?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, concatenation, space

```
    $hall_members[$count] = $allUserData[1] . $allUserData[2];
```

allUserData[1] is the first name of a user
allUserData[2] is the surname of the user, and i want to concatenate the two and add it into a new array which is hall members, results are currently appearing as forenamesurename without any spaces, how do i make my example into forename surename.

Comment: `$hall_members[$count] = $allUserData[1] . ' ' . $allUserData[2];` or perhaps `$hall_members[$count] = implode(' ', array_slice($allUserData, 1, 2));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$hall_members[$count] = $allUserData[1] . ' ' . $allUserData[2];
```